# Is there a default margin or padding for a Grid in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to specify two grid rows next to each other.  But seems like there may be a default padding.  I saw a lot of posts about this but none saying what the default might be.

Is that the case that there is a default and if so then is it possible to override this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has a `ColumnSpacing` and `RowSpacing` defaults. To override this, just set `<Grid RowSpacing=0 ColumnSpacing=0>`.

The defaults in grid can be found at the source code (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Grid.cs)

Comment: To clarify, it is the **parent** object's **spacing** (row/columnspacing for grid, spacing for stacklayout) that matter here. So this answer is **correct ony** if the two grids are themselves inside a grid, in which case the outer grid is what needs these properties set to zero.